# Type and non-type template parameters to use interchangeably

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible in C++ to declare some class so that it would be allowed to pass integer value or type as template parameter?

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <auto I>
struct Foo {};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo1;
    Foo<1> foo2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would you use that, and what for?

Comment: @BaummitAugen. Very simple use-case is when you want to use some scalar type with extra value, e.g.: int + unknown value: `Storage<1>` and `Storage<Unknown>` where `Unknown` is just tag type. Most of the time `Storage` from integer literal would be enough, but sometimes we want to pass some special value/type.

Comment: Ok. The `integral_constant` stuff below should be what you need then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, that is not possible. As a workaround, you could use `std::integral_constant` in order to pass values homogeneously as types.

```
template <typename I>
struct Foo {};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo1;
    Foo<std::integral_constant<int, 1>> foo2;
}
```

With C++17, you can define

```
template <auto I>
using constant = std::integral_constant<decltype(I), I>;
```

to avoid some boilerplate.

Comment: Upvote went for the idea how to avoid boilerplate. Nice.